# Custom Compiler Flags for GoogleSignIn/Crashlytics/Firebase

Tags: ios, google-signin, crashlytics, compiler-flags

I'm trying to resolve compiler flags, like -Wno-auto-import, in my main project. But I can't set the compiler flags for GoogleSignIn/Crashlytics/Firebase pods. I tried to add this following code to my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['WARNING_CFLAGS'] = "$(inherited) -Wno-auto-import"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm still getting auto import compiler errors. It's working fine for facebook signin and all other pods. The compiler flags are also listed under Pods -> GTMOAuth2 -> Apple LLVM 9.0 - Custom Compiler Flags -> Other Warning Flags -> -Wno-auto-import

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to silence *all* cocoapod warnings by specifying this flag in your pod file:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

You can be a bit more granular and specify it per pod if you wanted:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', inhibit_warnings: true
pod 'Crashlytics', inhibit_warnings: true
pod 'Firebase', inhibit_warnings: true
```

This *may* not work if you have `-Weverything` enabled in your project, which is generally discouraged because it includes warnings that are buggy or still in development. This flag will give you false-positives for your cocoapod frameworks. More information here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development/124574#124574

---

If you still wish to try manually edit the warning flags - then your code sample looks fine, make sure it's not getting overwritten by an `xcconfig` file

Also make sure you do a clean so that no warnings are left over from previous builds! Xcode can be a pain and keep them around longer than they need to be sometimes. Check the actual build log produced to validate if they are still being raised

Comment: I have "-Weverything -Wno-gnu -Wno-float-equal -Wno-double-promotion -Wno-objc-missing-property-synthesis -Wno-nullable-to-nonnull-conversion -Wno-overriding-method-mismatch -Wno-direct-ivar-access -Wno-missing-variable-declarations -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-used-but-marked-unused -Wno-method-signatures -Wno-cstring-format-directive -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-bad-function-cast -Wno-unreachable-code-break -Wno-idiomatic-parentheses" flags enabled in my project right now. I also added "inhibit_all_warnings!" to my Podfile which is not working. I cleaned the project multiple times.

Comment: See my note about `-Weverything`

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue.